# Communicating with a DLL

Tags: windows, dll, ipc, winsock2, winsock-lsp

I have an LSP (Layered Service Provider) DLL, but once it's installed in the catalog, how to i communicate with it in my program? My LSP is based largely off of Microsoft's sample LSP.

I was reading komodia's write up on LSP DLL's and they state that you need IPC(intern Process Communication) via mail slots, named pipes, COM, etc.

Im having trouble accumulating more info regarding this.
What is the best, most efficient way to communicate with my LSP DLL as it operates on the catalog?

Thanks.

Comment: What program are you trying to access the dll with?  I'm assuming you have the source for it and are building a tool to interrogate the dll.  What is the program written in?  What type of dll is the LSP?  Is it a COM dll?  Native? Managed?

Comment: Yes i have both source codes, the LSP is built on the Microsoft Sample one they provide in the PSDK in C++ - native. IDK how to tell if its a COM dll.

Comment: I took a brief look at the docs on LSP.  What are you trying to accomplish by inserting a layer into the network stack?  This could be dangerous to the system, as well as be flagged by antivirus systems, etc.  There may be a better way to do what you want.

Comment: Application layer sniffing. How might i communicate with this LSP(DLL)?